# How to delete todo item with js typescript (NOT ONLY BY NAME OF THE TASK)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm new to ts, so I've created a to-do list, but when I'm completing the task with the same name as others, they all disappear.
It looks like I just need to add one more criteria to filter or smth, but I don't know how to do it.
I've pinned 3 different code files that I use.

```
import React, {FC, useState, ChangeEvent} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import TodoTask from './Components/TodoTask'
import { ITask } from './Interfaces';

const taskInitialState = {taskName: "", deadline: 0, description: ""};

const App: FC = () => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState<ITask>(taskInitialState);
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<ITask[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setTask({...task, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  };
  
  const addTask = (): void => {
    setTodoList([...todoList, task])
    setTask(taskInitialState);
  }

  const completeTask = (taskNameToDelete: string): void => {
    setTodoList(todoList.filter((task) => {
      return task.taskName != taskNameToDelete
    }))
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
        <div className='inputContainer'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your task" name="taskName" value={task.taskName} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="number" placeholder="Deadline in days" name="deadline" value={task.deadline} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name="description" value={task.description} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
        <button onClick={addTask}>Add Task</button>
      </div>
      <div className='todoList'>
        {todoList.map((task: ITask, key: number) => {
          return <TodoTask key={key} task={task} completeTask={completeTask} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TodoTask.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { ITask } from '../Interfaces';

interface ITodoTask {
    task: ITask;
    completeTask(taskNameToDelete: string): void;
}

const TodoTask = ({ task, completeTask }: ITodoTask) => {
    return (
    <div className='task'>
        <div className='content'>
            <span className='taskName'>{task.taskName}</span>
            <span className='duration'>{task.deadline}</span>
            <span>{task.description}</span>
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => {completeTask(task.taskName)}} >Complete</button>
    </div>

    )
}

export default TodoTask;
```

Interfaces.tsx

```
export interface ITask {
    taskName: string;
    deadline: number;
    description: string;
}
```

Comment: Add a property to your model that acts as a unique if (you could use a uuid, for example) and use that to delete rather than the name property

Answer (score 0):

- You need change parameters of your function completeTask is object type ITask.
- Passing a value to your function completeTask is a task.
- use JSON.stringify() and compare with your task in filter function.
  Hope my answer helpful.